# Disable "via" http header in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, http-headers

Please can you help me in disabling the Via http header in spring boot in response. I tried writing some value (My-UI) for via header in SecurityConfig.java but it is not working. In response i have something like

Via : MY-UI, 1.1 xxxx.host.tv

The code I used is

```
   http.headers().addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("via","MY-UI"))
```

--Editted---
The code and method

```
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    http.headers().disable();
```

---Update----
This works locally. Only when it is deployed to remote server we get the server name is appended.

Regards
Viji

Comment: Please can someone help me with your suggestions. I am unable to complete this task

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
httpSecurity.headers().addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("via","MY-UI").writeHeaders(request, response););
```

If you want to disable it completely;

```
httpSecurity.headers().disable()
```

Comment: Hi @Habil,  i tried the code httpSecurity.headers().disable() , But it is not working. Please can you let us know for suggestions

Comment: httpSecurity.headers().addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("via","MY-UI").writeHeaders(request, response););  We don't have request and response in our method.  I have provided the code in the editted section

Comment: Hi Habil, Please can you provide your response. httpSecurity.headers().disable() is creating problems in UI loading.

Answer (score 0):

The server was having httpd.conf. I disabled the proxy and was able to get rid of via header. 
Thanks to @habil for the suggestion